# Rails - Jaybird: set seq name for generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jdbc, migration, generator, firebird

how can i set a custom seq name in migration file?

we use a firebird db with jdbc adapter.
in firebird, the column size is limit by 32.
so the error msg is: Name longer than database column size

we had the same problem with index, but there you can set a custom name:

```
add_index :table_name, :column, :name => "custom_name_index"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that firebird driver 
https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/blob/master/lib/arjdbc/firebird/adapter.rb

needs patching like in the oracle case 
https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/blob/master/lib/arjdbc/oracle/adapter.rb

```
IDENTIFIER_LENGTH = 31
def default_sequence_name(table_name, column = nil)
  "#{table_name.to_s[0, IDENTIFIER_LENGTH - 4]}_seq"
end
```